# How does the Website knows I am running from android

Tags: android, cookies, mobile, user-agent

I am trying to reach the https://tv.partner.co.il from an android device, it looks like the website knows that I am using my phone :

1. request desktop site not working
2. changed the user agent to the same as my desktop pc still not working

Something I noticed that when I login first and than change the user agent and toggle device on the Dev tools of chrome it still working so the verification is only before the login.

What would you recommend me to do so I can watch the website from android device.

Is there any solution to transfer the cookie maybe from the desktop to phone?

Comment: It's clear from your user-agent, more information can be found here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/114937/htg-explains-whats-a-browser-user-agent/

Comment: I connected my phone with usb to PC, opened chrome Dev tools and changed the user agent to the same as my PC, but still it's no giving me the desktop version

Comment: You mean, you've changed your "Phone" user-agent using chrome Dev tools on your PC? I believe it's not possible so.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't have the rep to comment, so an answer.*

When I look at my server logs, and analyse the visits from mobile phones, I note that besides the visit from the user's mobile browser, there is (often? always?) a visit by a component of the mobile phone's operating system. Here is an example (anonymized):

```
37.201.225.xxx - - [16/Apr/2018:09:01:39 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 318 "my.site.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; Moto G (4) Build/NPJS25.93-14-10; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 ACHEETAHI/1"
37.201.225.xxx - - [16/Apr/2018:09:01:40 +0200] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 318 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; Moto G (4) Build/NPJS25.93-14-10)"
```

As you can see, a second or so after the browser (Chrome) requested the favicon of my site, the [Dalvik virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) requested the favicon also. For Apple phones and tablets I see requests from CFNetwork besides the mobile browsers. I assume there are other such OS processes requesting the favicon on other mobile devices.

These requests would make it possible for me to identify a visitor from a mobile device, no matter what the user agent string reads.

---

Another possibility to identify a mobile device is by reading the screen format with Java Script. Mobile devices have distinct display sizes that make it possible to distinguish them from desktop or laptop computers.

*But this is all just a guess, so it should be a comment...*